# Navigate on React router dom v6 loop problem

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I using react-router-dom v6. But when i want navigate its going to loop. I just want if url isnt one of that routes just navigate to "foo" url. In v5 version i can do it easily with redirect. But in v6 havent redirect so i must use navigate. But its making loop. My code :

```
const Login = React.lazy(() => import("./login"));
export const AppViews = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={`${AUTH_PREFIX_PATH}/login`} element={<Login />} />
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={<Navigate to={`${AUTH_PREFIX_PATH}/login`} replace />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default AppViews;
```

What is wrong in that code i really cant figure out. When path is /auth/login shouldn't it open element Login basicly? Its going loop when i make like this. Thank you for replies!

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/navigate-on-react-router-dom-v6-loop-problem-z3ntr) and it seems to work without issue. `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={.....} replace />} />` is the v6 equivalent of the v5 `Redirect` component, it should works the same for the most part.

Comment: @DrewReese I tried upload to sandbox too but It didnt install dependencies i dont know why. So i sharing github link for you can check my codes. 

https://github.com/ugurcanucar/login-page.git

Can you check it please? I really struggle a lot with new react-router-dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could see you had an issue with absolute linking. Converting to relative linking seems to resolve looping issue. Either approach should work, but without digging deeper into your configs here's what worked for me.

views/index.js - append the wildcard `*` to the path so nested routes can be matched and rendered.

```
export const Views = (props) => {
  const { token } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={`${AUTH_PREFIX_PATH}/*`} element={<AuthLayout />} />
        <Route
          path="/*"
          element={
            <RouteInterceptor isAuthenticated={token} element={<AppLayout />} />
          }
        ></Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};
```

views/auth-views/index.js - Use relative routing, i.e. remove the `AUTH_PREFIX_PATH` prefixing.

```
const Login = React.lazy(() => import("./login"));

export const AppViews = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={"login"} element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="login" replace />} />
      </Routes>
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

Forked codesandbox from your github repo

[image: Edit navigate-on-react-router-dom-v6-loop-problem]

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach this works

```
const Login = React.lazy(() => import("./login"));
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

export const AppViews = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const Navigator = () =>{
   navigate(`${AUTH_PREFIX_PATH}/login`)
  }

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
      <Routes>
      <Route path={`${AUTH_PREFIX_PATH}/login`} element={<Login />} />
      <Route
        path="*"
        element={<Navigator/>}
      />
    </Routes>
  </Suspense>
  );
};

export default AppViews;
```

Comment: `Navigator` isn't a valid React component, it needs to return valid JSX. Why did you post a new answer instead of editing the previous one?